# Assign a different json value

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm having problems assigning a text value to a numeric value return from JSON. I am running a react project if there is any react method, but not particular.

```
{
 "TemplateAttributes":{"Type":"3"}
}
```

The below gets the above and assigns it to 'type'

```
let Type = TemplateAttributes[0].Type
```

I have this value returning:

```
return [{
        element:Type
   }];
```

But before this returns I want the "3" to be replaced with another value "foo" and only if its a "3".

Element will then return "foo" instead of a "3"

Comment: Mention the complete code which you have written to achieve it and it's not working

Comment: Not complicated: `if(Type === '3'){ TemplateAttributes[0].Type = 'foo';}`

Comment: Paste the value **"Type"** once, then I can suggest you the solution.